# How to detect contract creation timestamp in Ethereum blockchain nodes?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain

I am trying to detect timestamp in Ethereum node but there are no methods/functions.
How do we find this?

I am getting swap logs and parsing them but couldn't find direct way to detect contract creation date.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Contract creation date is not available using a direct method.

Blockchain explorers usually collect it the following way:

1. They scan **every** transaction on every block on the chain
2. If the [transaction receipt](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactionreceipt) contains non-null `contractAddress` property, it means that this transaction deployed a contract.
3. Time of the transaction (and effectively time of the contract deployment) is available as part of the block in which the tx was produced

Answer (score 1):

This is quite complicated. There is no method to get the Transaction that deployed the Contract.

First of all, there are multiple ways to deploy a contract:

1. Via the Deployment Transaction, here you will get the `contractAddress` in the tx receipt.
2. Via another contract, with `create2`/`create` method. For example in this way `Uniswap: Factory Contract` creates `Pair` contracts. And there is no API in RPC to find out this type of deployment. You need a node that can return such `"Internal Calls"`.

There are some **workarounds**. In your case, do you just need the timestamp? Then you have just to find the block when the contract was deployed.

1. The archive node.
2. Use binary search to find the block number, when `eth_getCode` returns not the empty data, and the previous one is empty.
3. Get the timestamp of the block.

If you need the transaction:

1. Use the previous method to find the block
2. Load transactions and their receipts.
3. Search for a Deployment Transaction, which has your `contractAddress` in the receipt.
4. If not found, almost always the contract emits an Event when creating another contract. So look into the `address`, `data` and `topics` to match your contract address of every log entry.

---

Not a universal workaround: if you know the Event which gets emitted in the constructor or by the parent's contract, you can search for it with `getPastLogs`.

---

You can use the 3rd party API, like https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts to get the **Get Contract Creator and Creation Tx Hash**. After that:

1. Get the `blockNumber` from `transaction` fetched by `txHash`.
2. Get the `timestamp` from `block` fetched by `blockNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a service's API like Etherscan, I was able to find the original creation transactions for various contracts with this API call by requesting all transactions associated with an address in chronological order:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc

This address is Shiba Inu. [Looking at the first transaction in Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0a4022e61c49c59b2538b78a6c7c9a0e4bb8c8fce2d1b4a725baef3c55fb7363), the "To" field shows that this was used to create the contract ("[  0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce Created ] (Shiba Inu: SHIB Token)").

Documented here: https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address

If this doesn't work universally, it should at least get you quite close to the block or transaction which created the contract you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

A contract creation timestamp is effectively the timestamp of the transaction confirmation, which is included in a block's information.

You can make a call to a node using [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/geth-parity-proxy#eth_getblockbynumber) or consider using Etherscan's [contract creator](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts#get-contract-creator-and-creation-tx-hash) endpoint if you have a list of contract addresses to cycle through.